# Windows spot instance with permanent storage

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm a noob, since I started using AWS yesterday, and windows today after 14 years. But I have a decent experience with linux servers.

I built an app which needs a windows environment to run some code. I would like to fire up a windows spot instance, with a permanent storage, so that I can fire up and terminate the spot instances without losing the attached windows data.

Under linux I would simply attach a volume and run a script to create some symbolic links. What's the best approach with windows? Can I reuse the same volume as root device on multiple spot instances?

Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I reuse the same volume as root device on multiple spot instances?

Simply to clarify: it's not possible to use the same EBS volume on multiple EC2 instances simultaneous.

Assuming you mean not-simultaneously, you could reuse an EBS volume as the root volume, but you'd need to do the following:

1. Allow the new spot instance to launch
2. Shutdown the spot instance after it's started
3. Detach its root volume
4. Attach your "reusable" volume.
5. Make sure the volume attachment's "Delete on Terminate" flag is off.

Doing this would require the assistance of some off-server scripting since the server cannot do this itself in the stopped state.

Aside from this, you could re-use a "D:" drive. On spot instance launch:

1. Attach the "reusable" volume to the instance as a secondary volume (such as /dev/xvdb)
2. Using `DISKPART`, map the new disk as a D: drive
3. Access the persistent volume as D: drive knowing that C: drive is disposable

The above should be done using scripting inside your EC2 spot instance on first launch.

References:

- `Diskpart` - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc770877.aspx

Comment: yes I meant non simultaneously. Couldn't I reuse the same EBS without having to detach one first by using an AMI?

Comment: No. When an instance is launched from an AMI, it'll have totally new EBS volumes. It cannot be launched with a pre-existing EBS volume attached. You must launch the instance, stop it and detach it's default volume and attach your desired one.

Comment: then how can nvidia distribute an AMI with their drivers preinstalled?

Comment: They launched an instance from a base AMI, installed the drivers, then created an AMI from that instance which you can then use.